# How do I implement a scholarly citation style in an online format?

Tags: academic-writing, citations, resources, chicago-manual-of-style

I am part of a group starting an online, submissions-based journal of critical writing specific to my field. As the writing will be academic, we will need a formal citation process. We have decided to go with Chicago.  However, I am having a tough time finding specific information about using Chicago citations in an online format.

More specifically, I am not sure how to adapt Chicago style to an online format. This style was created with the typed and printed page in mind, so I was wondering if there are any guidelines or commonly accepted tweaks to traditional Chicago style that make it more successful in an online format.

Does anyone know of any resources that can help me with this?

Comment: Why do you think that the citation style should differ between online and printed publications? Shouldn't the format always be the same? I'm not familiar with Chicago, but in APA the medium of publication does not matter, citations must always have the same format and you could simply look in the APA Manual to learn this. I would guess that for other styles this is similar.

Comment: What What said. Or do you mean that you are not sure how to adapt Chicago style to references TO an online publication?

Comment: Welcome to Writers.  Are you the same stila as [this user](http://writers.stackexchange.com/users/13470/stila)?  If you've accidentally created two accounts, you can use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page to ask that they be merged so you'll have all your posts on one account.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the way in which citations are implemented over on Living Reviews in Relativity [[link]](https://www.springer.com/physics/theoretical%2C+mathematical+%26+computational+physics/journal/41114).  For a specific example see the article [Massive Gravity](https://www.emis.de/journals/LRG/Articles/lrr-2014-7/articlese1.html).

In the second paragraph on that page, click on the citation numbered 287.  You'll get a little pop-up that follows the usual citation style, but annotated with hyperlinks.